# Using Action With Parameter, But Parameter Is Supplied In Calling Method

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, action, func

Assume that you have the following method:

```
public static void TestMe <T>(Action action)
    {
        List<T> collection = new List<T>();
        //Stuff gets added to "collection" here
        action(collection);
    }
```

This will give a compiler error since the above have no parameters.

However, I don't want a parameter for the collection, since this will get filled in the TestMe method. If I correct the usage, it looks like this:

```
public static void TestMe <T>(Action<List<T>> action)
        {
            List<T> collection = new List<T>();
            //Stuff gets added to "collection" here
            action(collection);
        }
```

But I cant do this, because then when I call TestMe, it wants the collection to be available as a parameter. Is there anyway around this?

Comment: I don't understand what the issue is. Can you expand a little?

Comment: Could you, say, give an example of how you call `TestMe`, and explain what you do not like with it in detail?

Comment: Certainly. I am trying to call, in the above example, the TestMe method with the Action parameter being a void method that takes a collection as a parameter. However, with the corrected usage, in the second example, it appears that the compiler demands that the collection be available for when the TestMe method is called, whereas I plan on building the collection within the TestMe method.

Comment: Can you update your question with an example of how you want to call `TestMe`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's test it:

```
public static void TestMe<T>(Action<List<T>> action)
{
    List<T> collection = new List<T>();
    collection.Add((T)(object)"123"); //I do not know, how you fill the collection
    action(collection);
}
```

1. You can use lamda expression to specify the action; `l` here is just a parameter:

   ```
   TestMe<string>(l => l.ForEach(s => Console.WriteLine(s))); //outputs: 123
   ```
2. You may specify a method with the necessary signature:

   ```
   public static void Foo<T>(List<T> list)
   {
       list.ForEach(s => Console.WriteLine(s));
   }
   ```

   and call `TestMe` then:

   ```
   TestMe<string>(Foo);     //outputs: 123
   ```

Both these examples show that your `TestMe` does not require the `List<T>` to be called and do use the collection specified within the `TestMe` method.

---